# Display passed data from one Ionic 3 vpage to another

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic3

So, I have data displaying on one page with a (click) event that passes data to another page, except I can only get the data to print in the console and not the page itself.  I've been at it for hours and am at my breaking point :)

I am only going to show the relevant code below to keep the post shortened (well, what I think is relevant)

**list2page.html**

```
...
<button class="list-item" tappable ion-item (click)="goToFeed(item)" *ngFor="let item of list2.items">
  ...
</button>
...
```

**list2page.ts**

```
...
goToFeed(item) {
  this.nav.push(ProfilePage, {item: item});
}
...
```

**profile.ts - it will print the entire item to console - see screenshot**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'profile-page',
  templateUrl: 'profile.html'
})
export class ProfilePage {

  constructor(
    public nav: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
  ) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    let veteran_first = (this.navParams.get('item.veteran_first'));
    console.log(this.navParams.get('item'));
  }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Replace `this.navParams.get('item.veteran_first')` with `this.navParams.get('item').veteran_first`

Answer (score 0):

You should define `veteran_first` as a class variable, not a local variable:

```
  export class ProfilePage {
  veteran_first; //------------------------> define it here
  constructor(public nav: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {}

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    // Assign to this.veteran_first
    this.veteran_first = this.navParams.get("item.veteran_first");
    console.log(this.navParams.get("item"));
  }
}
```

Then in `profile.html`:

```
<div>
    veteran_first = {{veteran_first}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Delcare a parameter on your model:

```
public data: any;
```

Then instantiate like so:

```
this.data = this.navParams.data;
```

or this should also work

```
this.data = this.navParams.get('item');
```

then after you have it, you should be able to drill into it

```
this.data.item.veteran_first
```

or something to that effect. I have used both ways to fetch data passed thru the navCtrl.